# Make cron run APT commands every 24hrs

Tags: apt, cron

I wrote a simple script that is basically apt-get update, upgrade, autoremove and autoclean, like this:

```
apt-get check && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
```

I put this into my crontab, opening the tab with `sudo`

```
0 24 * * * /home/ubuntu/script.sh
```

Would this make the script run every 24 hours? Or would it not work? I'm asking for educational purposes, I'm not looking for more efficient ways just yet.

Comment: The script will run...but it will hang. `apt-get update` without the '-y' flag asks for user input. The next morning, when you kill the stuck headless process, also remember to release the apt lockfile since apt could not. (the lockfile simply makes sure that a maximum of one instance of apt can be running at a time).

Comment: **VTC** As too broad because OP doesn't have a specific problem to solve. It's almost like fishing or throwing something into the wind to see if something might be a problem for someone else some place else.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what script you are trying to run, your crontab entry will not work.

24 is not a valid entry for the hours field. It accepts 0 - 23, where 0 is midnight.